# ajax is not working for a list of items but working for the first item of the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working with a product list in which i want to add a product in the cart. but unfortunately the ajax code only works for the first item in the list. or the code works if i go to the details page where the page contains a single product. Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addToCart").click(function(){
            var productId  = $("#productId").val(); 

            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo site_url('cart/addToCart/'); ?>',
                data:{productId:productId},
                type:'POST',
                success:function(data){
                    // Change css value of "result" div and Display
                    $("#result2").css("display", "block");
                    $("#result2").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="icon">
<input type="hidden" id="productId" value="<?php echo $product->productId; ?>">
<a href="#" id="addToCart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" / "only works for first item in the list"?  Are you saying that `productId` is always the first item in the list? Or that the AJAX call only works the first time?  Or, that you have many inputs `id="productId"`, and that only the first one of the products works?

Comment: only the first one of the products works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have more than one element with the same ID on it.  In your case, you have the same ID for both `addToCart` as well as `productId`.

I've modified the code below so that it will work for as many product(s) as are listed on the page.  It can do this by finding the [sibling](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) element that is the product id:

```js
    // no-conflict safe "shorthand" document ready
    jQuery(function($) {
        // Access the button by class
        $(".addToCart").click(function() {
            // Find the sibling with the class productId
            var productId  = $(this).siblings(".productId").val(); 

            $.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo site_url('cart/addToCart/'); ?>',
                data:{productId:productId},
                type:'POST',
                success:function(data) {
                    // Change css value of "result" div and Display
                    $("#result2").css("display", "block");
                    $("#result2").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="icon">
<input type="hidden" class="productId" value="<?php echo $product->productId; ?>">
<a href="#" class="addToCart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using an `id` to target the `addToCart` button and `id`s can only be used on a single element on a page. On pages with multiple products this means there are multiple elements using the `addToCart` `id`.

Change the `addToCart` id to a class, then change the selectors appropriately (ie `$(.addToCart)`).